Rotate QCursor - PyQt5
I want to rotate the icon of the QCursor.
I tried using the following code, but it seems not working, I can't see the actual Size icon (I see the default icon) and the rotation is't taking place.
class CircleBoundary(QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__():
         curor = QCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
         rotated_pixmap = curor.pixmap().transformed(QTransform().rotate(180))
         new = QCursor(rotated_pixmap)
         self.setCursor(new)


As the pixmap() documentation explains, it's "only valid if the cursor is a pixmap cursor". Meaning that if you're using standard cursors provided by the system, you'll get a null pixmap, which cannot be used with QCursor (you should probably see a warning in the debug output, at least if you run the program in a terminal or prompt). The only option you have is to use a custom cursor (providing a valid QPixmap).
